# Bash while loop - break and exit (DIE script DIE!!!)

Tags: bash, while-loop, exit, break

All I want from this script is to ssh to the host, and check if the process is alive, and if it is not, I want the littel script to die. 
Does not die though. It stops, and then starts up again on the ssh is successful again. 
I want death though.

```
#!/bin/bash
iterate=0
while [ $iterate -le 20000 ]
do
   rc=$?
   ssh -q -T coolhost "ps -ef | egrep '[i]cool-process' | grep wrapper  "
   if [[  $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
       sleep 2
       iterate=$((iterate+1 ))
   else
       break
       exit 1
   fi
done
```

It will iterate to 2000, however if the remote process breaks, it will not die. It will not break and exit.

this will work - but won't sleep - if I put a sleep the rc goes to 0 and is never dies. 
so this works but is too basic.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
while : ; do
   ssh -q -T coolhost "ps -ef | egrep '[i]cool-process' | grep wrapper" > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: Instead of `ps -ef | grep ...`, use `pgrep`.  This is a much more direct way to search for processes by name (note useful options like `-u` and `-f` which you may want or need).  It will return a failure code if the process is not found.

Comment: `rc=$?` should be on the line following `ssh`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `rc=$?` before the `ssh` command, and the last command was the `test` (`[`) command, which just succeeded, so when you test `if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]` the answer is always 'yes, it does'.

It's best to test the status of `ssh` directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
iterate=0
while [ $iterate -le 20000 ]
do
    if ssh -q -T coolhost "ps -ef | egrep '[i]cool-process' | grep wrapper"; then
        sleep 2
        ((iterate++))
    else
        break   # or exit 1
    fi
done
```